# .Net AES Implementation

Tags: .net, cryptography, aes

I'm implementing a login mechanism for a mobile device using bcrypt and AES. The user will have to login using a password, which will then be hashed with bcrypt and compared to the hash in the database. The login transaction will, of course, take place over SSL, and the server will be configured to only serve SSL. That part is pretty straightforward.

However, I will also want to store a cookie so the user does not have to log in each time. The cookie will be automatically deleted from the device after 24 hours. I was planning on storing an AES encrypted string comprised of a date-time stamp and the bcrypt hash. The AES implementation is where I'm having difficulty. I was planning on using [Encryptamajig](https://github.com/jbubriski/Encryptamajig) , which is "a simple wrapper to the .NET AES encryption algorithm functionality," but then I saw [this issue](https://github.com/jbubriski/Encryptamajig/issues/7) posted on it which has not yet been fixed. (The issue has to do with using the same derivation function to generate the IV as the key).

My question is, is this a huge issue that should prevent me from using this wrapper? 
(my cryptography knowledge is increasing, but still relatively low; however, if I understand correctly, this is close to the same issue that makes WEP so easy to crack)

If it is, is there a best/better practice for using .Net's [AES Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx)? It seems that most of the answers currently on SO are older, and don't deal with the AES class at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the cookie should be a random token stored in a autologin table in the database. Then you can invalidate those tokens without changing the user's password.

When using AES on .net, I'd use one of the built in classes, either [`Rijndael`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx) with a block-size of 128 or `Aes`. I'd only use other implementations, if I need the additional speed(The build in crypto classes are often slow).

Comment: The AES class is what I was planning on using, it just seemed that there are insecure ways to go about using it with respect to IV generation. I do like the token idea. Would a good way of doing that be storing the token in the DB along with a timestamp for it, so that if the token is passed after a certain amount of time it is invalid? On any login after that, the token and timestamp would simply be regenerated.

Comment: A three column table with token, userid and timestamp seem like a good idea. And don't forget to invalidate the tokens(simply delete them) when the user changes his password.

Comment: Definitely. Thank you. At this point it seems like the AES usage is overkill.